# How to count xargs arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I'm piping a large file (~5M lines) into xargs that I'm processing in batches using -L to limit to max-lines per command. The command I'm calling with xargs requires not only the arguments (one argument per line in the input file), but additionally a count of the number of arguments I am passing it as the first argument.

e.g. I have a file, `numbers.txt` containing the English words for the first 17 numbers, one per line.

`cat numbers.txt | xargs -n 3 echo` prints the following:

```
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
ten eleven twelve
thirteen fourteen fifteen
sixteen seventeen
```

As expected `echo` is called with 3 arguments, the max-lines limit, on each invocation except the last because we only have two lines remaining.

What I want is to call my target command with a count of the arguments passed followed by the actual args.

Extending the preceding example, `cat numbers.txt | xargs -n 3 sh -c 'mycommand "$#" "$@"'` *almost* gives what I want. Strangely (at least to me), the first argument is missing from both `$@` and `$#`.

That is, `cat numbers.txt | xargs -n 3 sh -c 'echo "$#" "$@"'` prints

```
2 two three
2 five six
2 eight nine
2 eleven twelve
2 fourteen fifteen
1 seventeen
```

rather than

```
3 one two three
3 four five six
3 seven eight nine
3 ten eleven twelve
3 thirteen fourteen fifteen
2 sixteen seventeen
```

which is what I would expect.

Why is this happening? How can I arrive at the expected output? I'm not married to this approach, if there is something simpler I could do please suggest.

Comment: Why would a command need the count of arguments as a separate argument? It can get that from `argc`.

Comment: BTW, if you're using xargs to process data that's one item per line, you should be using `-d $'\n'` if it's GNU xargs, or `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0` if it's BSD-style.

Comment: ...without either `-d` or `-0`, xargs tries to get clever and apply shell-like (but not quite shell-compatible) processing to your items.

Comment: @Barmar, ...I'm hoping there are other arguments _after_ the ones being appended in the real use case -- I've sometimes used the calling convention myself when I needed to be able to pass a command multiple arrays, or an array in a non-terminal position, and needed to be able to pass through arbitrary enough data to make a termination sigil unworkable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a placeholder to fill in `$0` so the first argument becomes `$1`.

```
<numbers.txt xargs -n 3 sh -c 'echo "$#" "$@"' sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an extra argument when passing arguments to `sh -c`, because the first argument is treated as `$0`, not an actual argument.

```
xargs -n 3 sh -c 'echo "$#" "$@"' sh
```